# maintenance page problems with redirecting

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hello Checked many other question about this but none of them helped

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
php_flag display_errors off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.11\.111\.11    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.php$    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance.php [R=307,L]
```

Ill ask short : Is there something wrong in the code because i get redirected  to maintenance page but my ip doesnt seem to be working and i dont get redirected to the other page.

Comment: Looks good to me. Sometimes browsers cache redirects, so if you have been playing around with this, it might still be looking at the old rule. Try clearing your browser cache or using a different one.

Comment: Do you need a `$` after this line? `!^111\.11\.111\.11    `

Comment: Yeah did all of those things still isnt redirecting me to the other page.

Comment: the trailing $ in the REMOTE_ADDR line shouldn't be necessary, since without it the condition would just match more ip addresses but still the intended one

Comment: have you checked, if the IP address visible to the web server is the one, you have configured? maybe there is a load balancer or something in between. maybe add a <?php var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?> to your maintenance.php to check

Comment: Whenever i add <?php var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?> the page goes blank :(

Comment: There is a missing ). Try `<?php var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); ?>`

Comment: ^ Adding that doesnt seem to help it only turns my pages blank